# Why should we have unit test for RCP application as fragment

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, junit4

I am writing unit test case for eclipse 4 RCP and I have gone through various tutorial

For Example: 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Testing/article.html

Most/Everyone recommend to keep test in a separate fragment project so that they can access the files in their host plugin. I have some question

1- What would be the drawback of keeping test in a separate plug-in or why fragments are preferred over plug-in ?

2- How transitive dependency is going to be resolved ? Fox example - if host plugin is depend upon some other plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fragment can access all the resources in the host plugin. In run-time, a host plugin and it's fragments is treated just like one.

But a plugin can only access the exported packages of plugins in the plugins dependencies. So if you use a plugin for unit testing, you have to export all the package for the unit testing plugin, even if you don't want other plugins to use these packages.